# Combine regex to convert raw hex for JSON

Tags: python, json, regex

New to regex. How to combine multiple replace like this into a single regex (ie with variables) over all or a range of hex values?

`s.replace(r'\xF1', '\xF1').replace(r'\xE1', '\xE1').replace(r'\xEA', '\xEA')`

where s are strings to be parsed by json.load, eg

`s = 'M : AU : \\xA0MDA:CON'`

Certain fragments containing hex cause sporadic errors:

`{'M': 77,
 ' ': 32,
 ':': 58,
 'A': 65,
 'U': 85,
 '\\': 92,
 'x': 120,
 '0': 48,
 'D': 68,
 'C': 67,
 'O': 79,
 'N': 78}`

**EDIT**

Only looking to convert hex values, not all escaped characters as those include control codes which are also problematic for json.loads.

Answer (score 0):

Since you simply want to convert escaped hex strings into literal strings with binary characters, you can first convert the string to bytes using the `encode` method, and then convert the bytes to a string using the `decode` method with `unicode-escape` as the encoding:

```
s = 'M : AU : \\xA0MDA:CON'
print(repr(s.encode().decode('unicode-escape')))
```

This outputs:

```
'M : AU : \xa0MDA:CON'
```

Comment: thanks but your method in addition to converting hex strings also converts control characters, eg `'\\n'` to `'\n'` which json.loads does not handle. Can you modify your approach?

Answer (score 0):

Wrangled this that seems to work for our logs:

```
hex_decoder = lambda s: re.sub(r'\\x([0-9a-fA-F]+)',lambda c: chr(int(c.group(1),16)),s)
```

Eg, given

```
s = '{"AU" : "\\xA0MDACON\\nNext Line is\\xE1then"}'
```

then:

```
hex_decoder(s)
```

correncly handles hex values and leaves control characters like `\n` as is:

```
'{"AU" : "\xa0MDACON\\nNext Line isáthen"}'
```

Is there a cleaner solution?